# Aligning picture with displaymath

Tags: math-mode, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have a small picture of a graph and I would like to align it with its adjacency matrix, defined within math environment, side by side on a page. I tried to use subfig package, but the matrix is then misaligned (it begins vertically in the middle of the picture).

EDIT:
I have

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{Graph1.png}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{minipage}{1.2in}
\begin{math}
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\end{math}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

If you include it in a document, you will see the matrix is "misaligned" - it is lower than the image. I would like them verticaly centered to the center.

If I add

```
\parbox{1.2in}{\includegraphics{Graph1.png}}
```

then it is working, but I get Overfull \hbox.

Comment: Hi Jakub, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you provide a screenshot of what you're looking for, ideally with [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I'm confident this problem can be solved, perhaps with `minipage`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{Graph1.png}}
```

does what you want?

Comment: Nice, that got me rid of the Overfull. Thank you.

Comment: Another way, with `amsmath`, is `\begin{gathered}\includegraphics{Graph1.png}\end{gathered}`